# How much water should a nursing dog drink?

Tags: dogs, diet, feeding, drinking, pregnancy

I've read that dogs need roughly an ounce of water per pound of body weight each day and that nursing dogs need more than that to produce milk. My pit bull terrier recently gave birth to a litter of 9 and she can easily drink that daily recommended amount in one sitting, 5 times a day.

Can nursing dogs have too much water? What's the ideal amount she should drink per day? Is it ok to leave her without water after bed time?

Comment: I have two general ideas about the increased water intake: She needs more water to "change it into milk" for the puppies (what seems to be logical) but also (if this is possible for dogs) she could drink more as symptom of an gestational diabetes. In case one she will not pee more than before, in case two she would pee a much more than before nursing, and the whole had started before the puppies got born. So case one is more probable.

Comment: Plus for a recent litter, there’s also the loss of blood and fluids that needs replenishment.